# Pack more than 4 components into RGBA_32 texture in vertex shader

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

**The problem**:

- Vertex Shader can fetchh texels only from non-mipmapped RGBA_32 images(128 bits floating point)
- I need more than 4 values per-vertex
- using multiple RGBA_32 images is overkill (I guess), at least I don't need so much precision for each single component)

So I need a way to pack more than 4 components inside the 4 RGBA values and of course a way to unpack those components inside the Vertex shader.

**Some of the components I need:**

- RGBA color (32 bits)
- Position   (16 bits per component so 48 bits in total)
- Normal     (?? bits)

Performance is not an issue (well I think any unpacking function would be better than sampling a RGBA_32 texture twice, also because those textures are big and every extra texture eats dozen MBs!)

The packing must be possible both inside a fragment shader (assume render target is used) and in portable C code (update parts of the texture from CPU when needed).

Comment: the RGBA_32 is the texture wich has 4x32bit floating points numbers for each channel

Answer (score 0):

<s>How about using multiple images each with less than 8 bits of precision per channel? For example two RGBA images with type `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4` and internal format RGBA4 (i.e. 4 bits per channel).</s>

Another possiblity is packing bits. For example two nibbles can be packed into an octet. So using a R8_G8_B8_A8 (i.e. GL_RGBA8) texture you could encode 16 elements.

Packing a component

```
uint8_t pack_nibbles(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    return (a & 0x0f) | ((b & 0x0f) << 4);
}
```

Unpack

```
ivec2 unpack_nibbles2(int c) {
    return ivec2(c & 0x0f, (c >> 4) & 0x0f);
}

ivec4 unpack_nibbles4(ivec2 c) {
    return ivec4(c.x & 0x0f, (c.x >> 4) & 0x0f,
                 c.y & 0x0f, (c.y >> 4) & 0x0f);
}
```

the later can be used like

```
uniform usampler2D tex;

/* ... */

ivec4 t = texture(tex, ...);
ivec4 a = unpack_nibbles4(t.xy);
ivec4 b = unpack_nibbles4(t.wz);
```

Comment: `Vertex Shader can fetchh texels only from non-mipmapped RGBA_32 images (128 bit floating point)`
mainly implementation dependent, my current GPU can handle only those textures inside vertex shader

Comment: @DarioOO: Opps, completely missed. That. Can you use integer internal format textures and bit manipulations?

Comment: I fear bit manipulations are only for GL 4.x (while I'm targeting GL 3). I would try to pack data via multiplication and extract with division and modulo, but I don't know if there are issues with that approach

Comment: @DarioOO: Bit manipulations are well defined in OpenGL-3 and required by the standard.

Comment: @DarioOO: There is this little line in the specifications. In GL4 it is: *"a floating-point value and integer textures return signed or unsigned integer values. The fragment shader is responsible for interpreting the result of a texture lookup as the correct data type, otherwise the result is undefined."* In GL3 the same section reads *"When not using a fragment shader, floating-point texture values are assumed, and the results of using integer textures in this case are undefined."* So the availability of integer textures might be a problem.

Comment: Infact I not assumed integer textures, I specified floating point. I have 4 floating point values, and need to extract more values from them (bit manipulation is well defined for floats too?)

Comment: @DarioOO: Bit manipulation with floats normally doesn't work. You probably can do something equivalent with floats, but this going to be really, really dirty.

Comment: wich is exactly the question.